# Unique function that gives an angle to a point of an interval.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

(Sorry for my poor English in advance, as it is not my first language. Sorry for the vague title too, as I didn't know how to summarize the topic of the question).

Here is an exercise that was proposed in my Differential Geometry class, but I think it requires some topological concepts I don't fully understand yet (we are coursing both subjects in the same year). Anyway, I have thought about it so much and it is giving me headaches.

> Let $\mathbf{x}:J\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a parametrized curve such that
>   $\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert \equiv1$. Let $t_{0}\in J$ and
>   $\alpha_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $\mathbf{x}\left(t_{0}\right)=\left(\cos\alpha_{0},\sin\alpha_{0}\right)$. Prove that there exists a
>   unique fuction $\alpha:J\to\mathbb{R}$ (that is
>   $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$) such that
>   $\alpha\left(t_{0}\right)=\alpha_{0}$ and
>   $\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)=\left(\cos\alpha\!\left(t\right),\sin\alpha\!\left(t\right)\right)$.
>   You can follow these steps:
>
> 1. Prove that $\exists\varepsilon>0$ such that the function $\alpha$ can be defined in
>      $\left(t_{0}-\varepsilon,t_{0}+\varepsilon\right)\cap J$.
> 2. Assume that $\alpha$ is defined in a closed interval $\left[a,b\right]\subset J$, with $t_{0}\in\left[a,b\right]$. Then
>      $\exists\delta>0$ such that $\alpha$ can be defined in
>      $\left[t_{0}-\delta,b+\delta\right]\cap J$.
> 3. Let $B:=\left\{ b'\in J:b'\geq a,\,\alpha\text{ defined in }\left[a,b'\right]\right\}$ and $b:=\sup B$. Then $b=\sup J$ and if
>      $b\in J$, then $b=\max B$.

Let $\mathbf{x}\left(t_{0}\right)=\left(\cos\alpha_{0},\sin\alpha_{0}\right)=\left(a_{0},b_{0}\right)$. We can determine $\alpha_{0}$ whether as $\alpha_{0}=\arccos a_{0}$ or as $\alpha_{0}=\arcsin b_{0}$ in the regions where this functions are well-defined. If the sine or the cosine nullify at a point, their inverse functions are not well-defined in a neighbourhood of that point. But they cannot be nullified at once, so we can always find a way to define the angle. If $a_{0}\neq0$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that the function

$$A:\left(t_{0}-\varepsilon,t_{0}+\varepsilon\right) \to \mathbb{R}
\\ t \mapsto \arcsin t
\\ t_{0} \mapsto \alpha_{0}$$

is well-defined and $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. If $b_{0}\neq0$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that the function

$$B:\left(t_{0}-\varepsilon,t_{0}+\varepsilon\right) \to \mathbb{R}
\\ t \mapsto \arccos t
\\ t_{0} \mapsto \alpha_{0}$$
is well-defined and $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. If both are different than zero, then $A=B+2k\pi$, $ k\in\mathbb{Z}$. We can find a neighbourhood of any point where all of this is true.

The professor gave the following hint too, but I don't understand how to use it.

We define the sets $J_{+}$ and $J_{-}$ such that $$J_{+}=\left\{ t\in J:t\geq t_{0}\wedge\exists\alpha:\left[t_{0},t\right]\to\mathbb{R}\text{ that is }\mathcal{C}^{\infty}\text{ s.t. }\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)=\left(\cos\alpha\!\left(t\right),\sin\alpha\!\left(t\right)\right)\right\}$$ 
$$J_{-}=\left\{ t\in J:t\leq t_{0}\wedge\exists\alpha:\left[t,t_{0}\right]\to\mathbb{R}\text{ that is }\mathcal{C}^{\infty}\text{ s.t. }\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)=\left(\cos\alpha\!\left(t\right),\sin\alpha\!\left(t\right)\right)\right\} $$

$J_{+}$ and $J_{-}$ are non-empty, as $t_{0}\in J_{+}$ and $t_{0}\in J_{-}$. They are also open and closed sets (intuitively, but I don't know how to explain it). Being non-empty, open and closed, then $J_{+}=J_{-}=J$.